# Jenkins behind NGINX

Tags: nginx, jenkins, proxy, centos

Nginx is only working for http://localhost, it doesnt work for something like http://localhost/jenkins.

Here is my configuration:

This works @ http://localhost, the login screen comes up and everything appears fine.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header      Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass            http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_redirect        off;
        proxy_read_timeout    90;
    }
}
```

... but i want to see jenkins @ http://localhost/jenkins

so here is what I put:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    location /jenkins/ {
        proxy_set_header      Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass            http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_redirect        off;
        proxy_read_timeout    90;
    }
}
```

...and it appears to redirect me to http://localhost/login?from=%2F and gives error 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you might be missing is telling Jenkins that you want the prefix to be /jenkins..

```
/bin/java -jar /opt/jenkins/jenkins.war --prefix=/jenkins
```

Comment: yep that was it. Thanks!